# custom entrypoint for docker stack deploy?

Tags: docker

I'm looking to add a custom entrypoint from the command line to my docker deploy stack command. Similar to how you can do `docker container run service command`.

Right now I do `docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml my-service` but this sucks because I cannot pass a command from the command line

Comment: You should have the command specified inside the Docker-compose file.

Comment: I know that but I want to create a bash script to dynamically add the entrypoint

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
#!/bin/bash

docker_stack_entrypoint="
  version: '3.5'
  services:
    my-service:
      entrypoint: my-command
"

# debug combined docker compose file
echo "$docker_stack_entrypoint" | docker-compose \
  -f ./docker-stack.yml \
  -f /dev/stdin \
  config

echo "$docker_stack_entrypoint" | docker stack deploy \
  -c ./docker-stack.yml \
  -c /dev/stdin \
  my-stack
```